# Circular view path exception with Spring framework And AngularJs

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I am relatively new to the Spring boot frame work. I had a basic web application built in Angular with Spring boot connected and to a Mongodb. The application allowed users to add todo lists and register for the the website. When the application started it returned the todolists stored in mongodb to the view. The user could register, and there details were stored in a Mongo repository.

When I added and implemented spring security I got the error message

```
Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

What I want to happen is, when the webapp loads, I want the index.html to be injected with todo.html. Then if a user logs in they will be directed to another page or some Ui feature to become available. At the moment I am stuck in this  **Circular view path**loop.

I have looked through the different answers but I still am confused as to what exactly is causing the issue. I believe it is in the **WebSecurityConfig** class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

  @Autowired
  UserDetailsService userDS;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

    http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/todos/*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
      .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
      .logout()
        .permitAll();
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth
      .userDetailsService(userDS);

  }

  @Override
  protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
      return userDS;
  }  
}
```

**AuthUserDetailsService**

```
@Repository
public class AuthUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
  @Autowired
  private UserRepository users;
  private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userdetails;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
      throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    todoapp.models.User user = getUserDetail(username);

    userdetails = new User (user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                enabled,
                accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(user.getRole())
                );

    return userdetails;
  }
  public List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {

    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    if (role.intValue() == 1) {
      authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
      authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }

    return authList;
  }

  private todoapp.models.User getUserDetail(String username){

      todoapp.models.User user = users.findByUsername(username);


    return user;
  }
}
```

**TodoController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/todos")
public class TodoController {

    @Autowired
    TodoRepository todoRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Todo> getAllTodos() {
        return todoRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Todo createTodo(@Valid @RequestBody Todo todo) {
        return todoRepository.save(todo);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Todo> getTodoById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        Todo todo = todoRepository.findOne(id);
        if(todo == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Todo>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<Todo>(todo, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Todo> updateTodo(@Valid @RequestBody Todo todo, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        Todo todoData = todoRepository.findOne(id);
        if(todoData == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Todo>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        todoData.setTitle(todo.getTitle());
        todoData.setCompleted(todo.getCompleted());
        Todo updatedTodo = todoRepository.save(todoData);
        return new ResponseEntity<Todo>(updatedTodo, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteTodo(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        todoRepository.delete(id);
    }

}
```

**RecourceController**

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
   @Override
      public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
          registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
          registry.addViewController("/api/todos").setViewName("home");
          registry.addViewController("/register").setViewName("register");
          registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
      }
}
```

**Any help will be greatly appreciated.**

This is the Project Layout.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `.html` to your view names:

```
registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("app/views/index.html");
registry.addViewController("/api/todos").setViewName("app/views/home.html");
registry.addViewController("/register").setViewName("app/views/register.html");
registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("app/views/login.html");
```

Spring Boot registers a `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` which is capable of resolving static resources under `static` folder.
Because you set `login` as view name `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` tries to load `static/login` which apparently does not exist.
Change it to `app/views/login.html` so that `static/login` becomes `static/app/views/login.html`.

Comment: I changed the registry.addViewController to the following. registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("static/views/index.html");

Comment: I have also added the project structure to the question.

Comment: Great. Updated my answer

Comment: I changed my addViewController routes as directed. I am no longer getting a Circular view path error, but the webpage now displays an error. This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Feb 14 16:06:49 GMT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Also when run localhost:8080         the url is localhost:8080/login