# javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [login]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to Spring Boot and want to add the Spring Security module to my previous project. I followed this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/). My Spring Boot version is `1.5.6.RELEASE`.

Here is the security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Here is the MVC configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
```

I can ensure that `home.html`, `hello.html` and `login.html` are located in `resources/templates/`. As I added the Spring Security part to a previous project, I also has an controller that handles jpa request

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/pgsql")
public class TestPostgreSQLController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/save")
    public @ResponseBody
    String process() {
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Neo", "Chan"));
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Luke", "Liu"));
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Ran", "Guo"));
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Joey", "Chen"));
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Larry", "Huang"));
        return "Done";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/findbyid")
    public @ResponseBody String findById(@RequestParam("id") long id) {
        String result = "";
        result = customerRepository.findOne(id).toString();
        return result;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/find")
    public @ResponseBody String find(@RequestParam("lastname") String lastName) {
        String results = "";
        for (Customer bauer : customerRepository.findCustomersByLastName(lastName)) {
            System.out.println(bauer.toString());
            results = results + bauer.toString() + "<br>";
        }
        return results;
    }


}
```

the pom.xml is like this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I build the project as jar package. When I visit the `localhost:8080/home` or `localhost:8080/login` address. It throws the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Problem is related with pom file, you should add Thymeleaf dependency and code will start works.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's long time after this question been asked but I found the answer here]
 try to add `registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login.html");`
that work for me hope it helps[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226942/circular-view-path-exception-with-spring-framework-and-angularjs/42228310#42228310)